# deftype - variable unbound

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to learn Common Lisp following C. Shapiro's [Common Lisp: An interactive approach](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~shapiro/Commonlisp/). I try to define the type bstree from chapter 18. 
My code is the following

```
(defun elementp (e)
  (or (characterp e) (numberp e) (packagep e)))
(deftype element ()
  '(satisfies elementp))
(defun bstreep (tree)
  (or (typep tree element)
      (and (listp tree)
           (= (length tree) 3)
           (typep (first tree) element))))
```

When I feed it to slime it gives the error `Undefined variable:ELEMENT`. What is wrong and how can I define the `bstreep` function?

Comment: The error message is clear: `element` is a variable. Why don't you try to pass the symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use the quoted form this way in all the `typep` usages?:

```
(typep tree 'element)
```

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem